# align dropdown and input with submit button in line

Tags: c#, asp.net, input

From bootstrap, it only have the combination of button with dropdown, if i want to have like this 
[image]

how should i write in my view?

from my view

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                     @Html.DropDownList("dateList", ViewData["dateList"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @id = "dateList", @class = "form-control" })
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" id="DCRDate" name="DCRDate" value="" />
                    <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Change</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i had this 
[image]

with André Franciscato Paggi codes
with span the dropdownlist it become like

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    @Html.DropDownList("dateList", ViewData["dateList"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @id = "dateList", @class = "form-control" })
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" id="date" name="date" value="" />
                <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Change</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: can you please include HTML source in question

Comment: Try using this CSS selector on submit button: `display: inline-table`. Use the selector inside `btn btn-default` class.

Comment: not working. it remain the same

Answer (score 0):

You can surround the button and the select with a span tag each, using the class "input-group-btn".

Here is a snippet:

```css
#myselect{
   width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <select name="myselect" id="myselect" class="form-control">
      <option selected>Foo</option>
      <option>Bar</option>
    </select>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" id="DCRDate" name="DCRDate" value="Input here" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Change</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: but my drop down list will be looks like this

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand what you just said. Can you explain it better?

Comment: i had edited my post, can u take a look there?
because comment i can't add any photos

Comment: You have to set a width to your select in this case.

Comment: No problem. If this worked for you, please remember to mark as answer, so that people know the answer.